# Formatting strings in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsstring

I'm building an iOS app which supports iOS 9 and above.

I'm using a UIWebView to display text stored in RTF documents which I am including in my app's bundle. I use the following code to insert the contents of the RTF files into the web view:

```
    NSURL *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:self.detailItem withExtension:@"rtf"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:filePath];
    [self.detailWebView loadRequest:request];
```

I am also using this to format the text to the correct size:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *fontSize = @"80";
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", [fontSize intValue]];
    [self.detailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

I never usually use JavaScript, so I'm not claiming to know how that works, but it enables me to adjust the fontSize string and achieve exactly the size that I want. The text displays in the same font as the rest of the stings in my app and everything looks fine.

The problem is that I want to be able to display some other text in the web view but I want to load it from an NSString in code, so I can append other strings and manipulate what the user sees. When I do this instead of loading from the RTF file, I get very different formatting:

```
[self.detailWebView loadHTMLString:@"This is a string" baseURL:nil];
```

This comes out in some nasty Times New Roman style font, and the text way smaller than the text that is loaded from the RTF files. I realise I can build some html tags into my string to add formatting, but I want to understand why the js formatting in webViewDidFinishLoad is not being applied, and what I can do to achieve universal formatting across all the strings I use in my web view.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some UIWebView text formatting on iOS, you can look at my approach with SWIFT. https://github.com/Vanyaslav/Swiftyyjsformatter
Hope, it helps.